# the atari environment is very weird

Tags: openai-gym

I installing gym successfully, but when making an atari environment, the result is very weird, which is monochrome and duplicates in a window as shown in the image.

I have tried to install atari several times but they have the same results.

```py
import gym
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env.reset()
for _ in range(1000):
   env.render()
   env.step(env.action_space.sample())
   # take a random action
env.close()
```

[image]

Comment: how did you make this atari environment? sharing code will help get an answer

Comment: Thanks very much! Just use the official code provided by Gym.


import gym
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env.reset()
for _ in range(1000):
    env.render()
    env.step(env.action_space.sample()) # take a random action
env.close()